# Problema con algoritmo para calcular ceros y numeros pares

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, while, programación-funcional, iteradores

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio para la facultad que me piden que cuando el usuario ingrese una serie de valores realice unos cálculos determinados. Si bien pude realizar la mayoría, estoy teniendo problemas en cuanto a contar la cantidad de ceros que aparecen en los números ingresados y la cantidad de números pares que fueron ingresados.

¿Cuál es el problema, dirán?: No encuentro lógica en ingresar un condicional dentro de un `while` donde hay otro condicional `if-else`; porque ya lo intente y no termina resultando como se espera. He tratado de resolver esto durante 5 horas y no he llegado a ningún lado, a ver si me pueden ayudar a entenderlo, les dejo el código amigos.

```js
function mostrar(){

let array = ["sumaPositivos", "sumaNegativos", "ceros", "numerosPares", "promedioPositivos", "promedioNegativos", "diferenciaPosNeg"];
let numeros;
let respuesta;

respuesta = "si";

numeros = 1;
numerosPares = 0
array [0] = 0; //sumaPositivos
array [1] = 0; //sumaNegativos
array [2] = 0; //ceros
array [3] = 0; //numerosPares
array [4] = 0; //promedioPositivos
array [5] = 0; //promedioNegativos
array [6] = 0; //diferenciaPosNeg

while(respuesta != "no")
{
    numeros++;
    numeros = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese un número"));
    respuesta = prompt("Desea continuar? Escriba 'si' para continuar, 'no' para salir");

    if(numeros >=0)
    {
    array[0] = array [0] + numeros;
    array [4] = array [4] + numeros;
    }
    else
    {
    array [1] = array [1] + numeros;
    array [5] = array [5] + numeros;
    }
    /*
    if (numbers % 2 == 0) {
        return array [3];
    }
    else
    {}
    */

    array [6] = array[0] - array [1];
}   

document.write("<h1>Resultados:</h1>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("La suma de los números positivos es :" + array[0]);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("La diferencia entre los números negativos es: " + array [1]);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Hay " + array [2] + " ceros.");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("La cantidad de números pares es: " + array [3]);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("El promedio entre los números positivos es: " + array [4] / numeros);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("El promedio entre los números negativos es: " + array [5] / numeros);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("La diferencia entre números positivos y negativos es: " + array [6]);}

mostrar();
```

Comment: Donde calculas los numeros pares?, donde calculas el promedio de negativos?, donde calculas el promedio de positivos?, donde calculas la diferencia de positivos y negativos?, en tu codigo parece que haz intentado mucho, pero la verdad no veo la mayoria de operaciones que debes realizar, ten en cuenta que nosotros no resolvemos tareas, en su lugar te ayudamos a resolver posibles errores que tengas o te ayudamos a que algo que no te cuadra te cuadre, en estos momentos y como esta tu codigo es como si nos pidieras realizarte todo el ejercicio entero.

Comment: Te aconsejo intentarlo un poco mas, pues la idea es que aprendas a realizar el ejercicio, si estas estancado en esas operaciones no es porque no puedas, si no porque directamente ni las haz intentado, espero que edites la pregunta y que pongas las partes en donde intentas realizar todas esas operaciones matematicas, pues estas no son complicadas de realizar. yo solo he contado que haz realizado correctamente 2 de 9, y no haz intentado 7 de 9.

Comment: Deberías ir almacenando cada número ingresado en un arreglo, para después poder analizarlos.

Comment: @Riven Si tenes razon, terminé logrando hacer el resto de las consignas cuando entendi cómo pero sigo sin comprender cómo calcular la cantidad de ceros y de numero pares ya que si agrego un if-else dentro de un while que ya tiene un if-else el programa se comporta de manera extraña, espero que ahora haya quedado mas claro, saludos

Comment: @Triby eso lo termine deduciendo pero tengo el problema logico que mancione arriba que todavia no puedo comprender. Lee el codigo nuevo para saber a que me refiero, deje un comentario con lo que se supone que iba a escribir

Comment: @Concord, solo basta con meter condicionales en el `while` **sin miedo**, y definir variables que funciones como contadores e incrementen dependiendo si se cumple la condición (si el número es 0 o o es par).

Comment: @Concord, te invito a leer [¿Bajo qué circunstancias puedo agregar "urgente" o frases similares a mi pregunta para obtener respuestas más rápido?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4771/21)

Comment: Por otro lado, poner uno o varios condicionales dentro de un bucle puede hacer todo el sentido del mundo o no, dependiendo de la lógica de tu solución. Los ejercicios están destinados a que vayas desarrollando tu habilidad para conceptualizar el problema y su solución, además de poder expresarlo en código. Creo que te has sentado a escribir la solución antes de comprender bien el problema o cómo vas a solucionarlo. Sugiero que inicies haciendo todo en papel primero. Cuando lo hayas hecho tendrás más claro como llevarlo a una computadora.

Comment: Finalmente, utiliza nombres de variables que sean fáciles de interpretar y recordar. Requiere un mayor esfuerzo entender lo que hace este código `array [4] = array [4] + numeros;`, que lo que hace este otro `totalNumerosPositivos = totalNumerosPositivos + nuevoNumero;`. Sugiero siempre utilizar el segundo. Es cierto, escribes unos cuantos caracteres más, pero estos son, por mucho, más baratos que el tiempo de todas las personas que lean ese código.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No es necesario realizar los cálculos mientras se van ingresando datos, eso solo debe hacerse hasta el final y, aparte, creo que se puede simplificar al usar solo un *prompt*.

Con [*array*.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) se pueden obtener "sub arreglos" con los elementos que cumplen la condición especificada.

Con [*array*.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) se pueden sumar los valores de un arreglo.

```js
let numeros = [];

while(true) {
    let respuesta = prompt('Ingresa un número o teclea "No" para terminar');
    // Se hizo clic en cancelar o respuesta es "No"?
    if(respuesta === null || respuesta.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
        // Salir del ciclo
        break;
    }
    // Agregar respuesta a números
    numeros.push(parseInt(respuesta));
}
// Obtener pares e impares
let par = numeros.filter(v => (v % 2) == 0);
let non = numeros.filter(v => v % 2);

// Suma de pares e impares
let parSum = par.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
let parNon = par.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);


// Total de ceros
console.log(numeros.filter(v => v == 0).length);
// Total y suma de pares
console.log(par.length, parSum);
// Total y suma de impares
console.log(non.length, nonSum);

// Obtener positivos y negativos
let pos = numeros.filter(v => v > 0);
let neg = numeros.filter(v => v < 0);
```

Si quieres seguir haciendo las operaciones dentro del ciclo, no es necesario anidar condiciones, porque cada número puede entrar hasta en <strike>3</strike> 2 categorías (0 = cero, par <strike>y ¿positivo?</strike>, -2 = par, negativo)

```js
let array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    while(true) {
        let respuesta = prompt('Ingresa un número o teclea "No" para terminar');
        // Se hizo clic en cancelar o respuesta es "No"?
        if(respuesta === null || respuesta.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
            // Salir del ciclo
            break;
        }
        // Agregar respuesta a números
        let num = parseInt(respuesta.replace(/\D/g,'')) || 0;
        // Es par?
        if((num % 2) == 0) array[1] ++;

        if(num == 0) {
            // Es cero?
            array[0] ++;
        } else if(num > 0) {
            // Positivo
            array[2] += num; // suma
            array[3] ++; // contador
        } else {
            // Negativo
            array[4] += num; // suma
            array[5] ++; // contador
        }
    }
/*
array [0] = 0; //ceros
array [1] = 0; //numerosPares
array [2] = 0; //sumaPositivos
array [3] = 0; //contadorPositivos
array [4] = 0; //sumaNegativos
array [5] = 0; //contadorNegativos
  //promedioPositivos
  //promedioNegativos
  //diferenciaPosNeg
*/
// Total de números ingresados (para calcular promedios)
let totalNum = array[3] + array[5];
console.log('Ceros ingresado:', array[0]);
console.log('Pares ingresados:', array[1]);
console.log('Suma positivos:', array[2]);
console.log('Positivos ingresados:', array[3]);
console.log('Suma negativos:', array[4]);
console.log('Negativos ingresados:', array[5]);
console.log('Promedio positivos:', array[3] / totalNum * 100);
console.log('Promedio negativos:', array[5] / totalNum * 100);
console.log('Diferencia:', array[2] - array[4]);
```

Comment: Te voto negativo porque ingresé los números `1, -1, 2`, y eso me da como promedio de positivos 66.66666 y promedio de negativos 33.333333 (en positivo). Además, viendo que es una pregunta de las escuela, cuestiono el hecho de darle una solución completa, pues eso podría evitar que desarrolle la lógica y, al final, el curso se trata de eso. (mi voto negativo, sin embargo, no es por eso, sino porque el algoritmo no hace bien los cálculos, como ya dije).

Comment: El promedio de 1 y 2 es 1.5. El promedio de -1 es -1.0. No veo como eso puede ser cuestión de _perspectiva_.

Comment: Ah, ya veo, creo que vos estás pensando en porcentajes. La relación de números positivos/negativos con respecto del total de números ingresados... pero eso no es un promedio, jaja.

Comment: Bueno, creo que podemos estar de acuerdo que el código del AP no está correcto. (AP es el término de SOes, que significa _Autor de la publicación_, en español). Un saludo.

Comment: Como dije en un comentario anterior... el código del AP es difícil de leer... esos nombres de variables no ayudan. Después de un día completo (es la 1AM por acá), ni loco trato de entender lo que dice ese código... :D. Pero la ejecución de la respuesta dice "promedio de XXX" y, pues, yo espero ver un promedio.

Comment: @jacguate estoy 3 unidades adelantado a lo que va mi curso, estudio a mi propio ritmo y no voy a esperar mas de 1 mes para tener una respuesta, por eso consulto esto con gente que tiene mas experiencia. No quiero que me hagan nada, ya que ni siquiera es una "tarea" si no que me ayuden a comprender lo que estoy haciendo mal en este caso, no creo que les cueste tanto a ustedes que estan experimentados y a mi se me explota el cerebro pensando qué puede estar mal. El día que esté en sus lugares haré lo mismo con quienes estaran donde estoy ahora. Disculpen si el codigo no es 100% legible

Comment: @Concord, tómalo con calma, jachguate no pretendió atacarte, solo hizo una observación respecto al tipo de respuesta y, tiene razón, hay que tratar de que quienes preguntan se lleven aprendizaje y no solo un código funcional.

Comment: @Concord, por mi parte, trato de responder con comentarios para lograr un aprendizaje y, casi siempre, solo cuando veo un esfuerzo previo por parte de quien pregunta.

Comment: @Triby creeme que hice todo el esfuerzo posible pero había ciertas cosas que no entendía, y por suerte lograron ayudarme. Les agradezco mucho a quienes se tomaron el tiempo de poder explicarme qué era lo que estaba haciendo mal y ayudarme a entender el procedimiento lógico del proceso. Básicamente empecé a programar en JS hace una semana, y yo creo que el haber llegado hasta acá, para mí, es un gran avance ya que no sabía absolutamente nada de este lenguaje. Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: @Concord, se nota que estás intentando hacer las cosas por ti mismo, si hay algo que no entendiste, pregunta y trataré de aclarar. Si la respuesta te fue útil, por favor márcala como aceptada.

Comment: @Concord no me lo tomes a mal. Dejé comentarios a tu pregunta de lo que veo que podrías mejorar en tu código y mi intención es ayudar y estoy seguro que la de todos los que escriben respuestas por aquí es la misma.

Comment: Esta solucion, a este momento, sigue dando mal.. ahora llega a dar nan porque no sanitiza la entrada :(

Comment: @gbianchi, gracias, ya está corregido.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente tienes problemas con la lógica que esta aplicando, sin embargo, es un problema básico de acumuladores y contadores, con los acumuladores sumas las coincidencias que quieres sumar normalmente es del tipo acum = acum + num, y luego dado que tienes que sacar promedios debes poder contar cada coincidencia de forma separada, los contadores son del tipo, cont = cont + 1. Y por último, nada te impide que dentro de una decisión uses otra para segregar los 0 de los mayores a 0. Saludos!